# c++ How to properly return an object from a function

Tags: c++, object, set

I am writing a program dealing with different operations with sets and some of the functions I am given are supposed to return objects. `SoS` is an object declared in the header file and has data members `m_vos`  (a vector of strings) and a boolean. In the function I am creating the new object and a new set.  How do I tie the set back with the object?

This is what I have:

```
SoS SoS::makeIntersection(const SoS& B) const {
    SoS intersection;
    vector<string> set1;
    vector<string> set2;
    vector<string> set3;

    set1 = this->m_vos;
    set2 = B.m_vos;

    //int totalElements;
    //totalElements = (set1.size() + set2.size());

    sort(set1.begin(), set1.end());
    sort(set2.begin(), set2.end());
    set_intersection(set1.begin(),set1.end(),set2.begin(),set2.end(),back_inserter(set3));

    return intersection;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch `set3` completely and build the intersection directly into the object:

```
set_intersection(set1.begin(), 
                 set1.end(), 
                 set2.begin(), 
                 set2.end(), 
                 back_inserter(intersection.m_vos));
```

Answer (score 1):

To return an object from a function, simply define the function as returning an object.  You need to define (or pass in) an object inside the function, modify it as desired, and return it.  An example that relates to your question is shown below.

```
Object myFunction() {
    // object to return
    Object myObject;
    // set of strings
    std::set<string> mySet;
    // convert to vector
    std::vector<string> myVector(mySet.begin(), mySet.end());
    // assign to object (the actual setting will be different)
    myObject.setVector(myVector);
    // return object
    return myObject;
}
```

Comment: Thats what I already have though. How do I link a data member to the object?

Comment: @MatthewHanson Do you need to convert the set to a vector of strings and then assign that vector of strings to the object's vector of strings?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I need to do.

Comment: @MatthewHanson I updated my answer with a set to vector conversion.  Of course, now that I see your code, you're already using `std::vector` and simply naming them `set1`, `set2`, etc. so you shouldn't need to convert from `std::set` to `std::vector`.